# MySQL : exclude rows where id appears in two separate columns of table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| id    | order_id  |  product_id |  category_id  |name | cost |  returned_product_id |
| 3100  |   900     |  0125       |      3        | Foo |  14  |  NULL                |
| 3101  |   901     |  0145       |      3        | Bar |  10  |  NULL                |
| 3102  |   901     |  2122       |      3        | Baz |  11  |  NULL                |
| 3103  |   900     |  0125       |      3        | Foo | -14  |  3100                |
| 3104  |   902     |  0125       |      3        | Foo |  14  |  NULL                |
| 3105  |   902     |  0125       |      3        | Foo | -14  |  3104                |
| 3106  |   903     |  0125       |      3        | Foo |  14  |  NULL                |
```

The id is a single line item of an order where product_id was included.  If the product is returned, a new line item is created with a new id.  There is one of each product, and it is possible to repurchase a returned item again, and return it again.

I'm joining the table data with data from other tables given certain conditions.  As a final condition, I am attempting to exclude any line items that were originally returned.  This is in attempt to perform a single query that essentially gives me all product_ids ever purchased and that have not been returned, like this:

```
select product_id 
  from orders o,
       line_items i 
 where o.state = 'paid' 
   and o.id = i.order_id  
   and i.category_id = 3 
   and i.product_id not in (select li.returned_product_id  
                      from line_items li 
                     where li.refunded_product_id is not null 
                       and li.product_id = 3)
```

Even though I have indexes on both the id and returned_product_id, the query above is really slow (thousands of lines), where if my subselect queried for the id, it's fast.

Comment: Can you show what desired result you want for your given example data?

Comment: There is no table aliased st in your query.

Comment: Sorry, Julian, I edited it out.

Comment: Mark, I'd like to get a list of the following product_ids, 0145, 2122, and 0125, that come from orders 901 and 902 and line item ids 3101, 3102, and 3106.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is from the table that you exposed the content, the line:

```
and i.id not in (select li.returned_product_id
```

will look in the id of the table and not the id of the product, wright?

That should be

```
and i.product_id not in (select li.returned_product_id
```

Comment: Yes, Sergio. Thanks for catching my mistake.  Any ideas on how to get the information?

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
 select distinct i.product_id from 
      line_items i left join line_items j
      on i.product_id = j.refunded_product_id            
      where j.refunded_product_id is null
```

?